# Removing polygons based on size of polygons in Python without using ArcPy?

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon

I am new to GIS. I want to remove some smaller polygons and only leave the polygons with a larger areas in Python scripts. Like this:

[image]

Here is the source files [Shape files: buildings](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Chvh1J8kUfQdxmDt0znYIg_AB9SJJ_Qr?usp=sharing). I am thinking whether I can set a threshold for the size of the areas then remove them, but I don't know how to do this in Python.

Using the help by @Iridium , then I am able to compute the area of the polygons by this link [Calculate area of polygons using OGR in python script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169186/calculate-area-of-polygons-using-ogr-in-python-script)

```
from osgeo import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dataSource = driver.Open(shapefile_to_be_used 1)
layer = dataSource.GetLayer()
new_field = ogr.FieldDefn("Area", ogr.OFTReal)
new_field.SetWidth(32)
new_field.SetPrecision(2) #added line to set precision
layer.CreateField(new_field)

for feature in layer:
    geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    area = geom.GetArea() 
    print (area)
    feature.SetField("Area", area)
    layer.SetFeature(feature)

dataSource = None
```

But how to filter out the polygons with small areas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a way to do these simple types of spatial operations in Python you can try [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/) which is a spatial extension to the (super popular and useful) [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library.

As a quick example, firstly read the data in as a Geodataframe object, and reproject to a [local projection](http://epsg.io/22281) (not being from South Africa, I hope this is right!).

```
import geopandas as gpd

buildings = gpd.read_file('buildings.shp').to_crs(epsg=22281)
```

At this point it's pretty easy to calculate the area for each geometry, and then threshold by some arbitrary number.

```
mask = buildings.area > 1000.  # metres squared
```

Finally, use the `mask` and [fancy pandas indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) to mask out the points of interest:

```
selected_buildings = buildings.loc[mask]
```

At this point you can plot the data out:

```
ax = buildings.plot(color="gray", figsize=(20, 8))
selected_buildings.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image: Subsetted buildings in blue]

Or save the data back out to disk:

```
selected_buildings.to_file('filtered_buildings.shp')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using OGR/GDAL to achieve your task.  One easy way to do this is calculate first the geometry in ArcGIS/QGIS (if possible), then iterate over the features with OGR and remove the ones with a value lower than X. Of course you could also calculate the area with GDAL/OGR like explained [in this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169186/calculate-area-of-polygons-using-ogr-in-python-script).

A good place to start is the Python GDAL/OGR cookbook [here](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/index.html)

Comment: I have to use python to realize this and no Arcpy. I wish I could have some python scripts example.

Comment: I edited my answer adding a link to calculate area of polygons with python and OGR. Shouldn't be complicated to edit the code to fit your needs. The Python GDAL/OGR cookbook I also linked you has tons of python scripts examples that directly fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is very helpful. But I still can't not find the solution to filter out small areas based on the size of the areas. I will try to do this. But if you have solution to this, I will appreciate very much.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it's not too late. 
I managed to do the same thing this way:

```
for feature in layer:
        geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
        area = geom.GetArea() 
        print area
        if area<=320000:(or any area you want instead of 320000)
            layer.DeleteFeature(feature.GetFID())
            continue
        feature.SetField("Area", area)
        layer.SetFeature(feature)
```

I found a similar script here: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/91667/osgeo.gdal.Polygonize

Hope it helps.